# Any good (and preferably free) G722 \ G722.2 implementation?

Tags: android, voip, codec, amr

I need to integrate those codecs for manual usage into Android.
I don't want the platform APIs, since they won't support my VoIP needs.
I need G722 and also G722.2 (supposed to be equivalent to AMR-WB).

Do you know of any good implementation? Maybe the ones in the Android source trees?

Answer (score 0):

There are implementation for [G.722, G.722.1 and G.722.2](http://opalvoip.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opalvoip/opal/trunk/plugins/audio/) in [OPAL](http://www.opalvoip.org/). I don't know how good they are, but they are designed as plugins, so you might even be able to use them without the OPAL framework around.